# Three unit apartment looking to have washer/dryer switch with "device" to tenants electric

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, dryer, washing-machine

Looking to see if there's a way or device that would allow a tenant to switch the washer/dryer that's in a common area to their electric breaker.

This is for a three-unit that we are rebuilding and want to remove the business side from handling an account for the electricity.

It would have to work with 220v and work for three tenants running on the same washer/dryer. My thought is a device that has three keys. When the tenant puts in their key the power switches over to their breaker and when the tenant removes their key the power flow stops.

This way each tenant is using their own electricity at a time and the business doesn't need to buy coin operated washer and dryer.

Comment: how do you power outside and hall lights if the business has no account? I don't know of a keyswitch that can handle dryer loads, so you'll have to get into a relay network and lots of complication and redundant home runs, which will be costly. Considering it cost $0.50 to do a load, wouldn't it be simpler to use the house feed and charge tenets $5 extra a month, or just chalk up the $15 to a business expense and deduct it to land at about $10/month? Considering how high rents are, I doubt $10 will make or break your operation.

Comment: Or put in an honesty box

Comment: I'd wager that the cost of the custom electric split setup will be higher than the coin laundry. Also, determining legally who has been paying for the use of the laundry will be more affirmable with the coin machines than the self-rolled power switcher. The local repairman probably knows how to fix the coin laundry too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-part problem:

1. Getting power from a tenant to the washer/dryer.
2. Ensuring power doesn't backfeed from one tenant to another.

Giving each tenant circuit breaker-style locking power shutoffs like you might see by a commercial AC unit would address #1.

For part #2, you need something like a pair of automatic transfer switches. These will sense which legs have power coming in and ensure only one ultimately is connected to the output, preventing backfeeding.

You would need to talk with your local inspector to see if they would sign off on such a setup.